# Function not defined at one point in its domain. Can we do the Riemann integral?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, definite-integrals, volume, riemann-integration

Consider a spherical coordinate system with origin at point $O$. Consider the following volume integral over $V$:

$\displaystyle \int_V \nabla \cdot \left(     \dfrac{\mathbf{A}}{r}    \right)  dV$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field.

Let $O \in V$.

$\dfrac{\mathbf{A}}{r}$ is differentiable everywhere except at origin $O$.

Therefore the volume integral has undefined output at one point in its domain.

> **Will this mere fact prevent us from computing the Riemann integral (by finding the antiderivative and applying the limits)?**
>
> I *think* I have read somewhere that if we redefine the undefined output at one point in such a way that the function becomes continuous, we can proceed to do the Riemann integral (by finding the antiderivative and applying the limits). Am I correct?